# Excel macro select between 2 specific words

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help to me in Excel macro ?

I need to select between 2 words what I defined before and delete it..

For example:
**"http:/ertwertw4r!%!+53445433333/cat.jpgThere is a dog"**

I need to select the text from "http:" till the ".jpg" and delete it or replace it for "", Cause I only need the "There is a dog" words...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim firstStr As String
Dim secondStr As String
Dim Str As String

Dim pos1 As Integer
Dim pos2 As Integer

firstStr = "http:"
secondStr = ".jpg"


For i = 1 To 500

    Str = Cells(i, 1) ' here i represents row, and 1 means first column

    pos1 = InStr(UCase(Str), UCase(firstStr))
    pos2 = InStr(UCase(Str), UCase(secondStr))

    If pos1 = 0 Or pos2 = 0 Then
        ' MsgBox "Something goes wrong"
    Else
        StringToDelete = Mid(Str, pos1, pos2 - pos1 + Len(secondStr))
        finalString = Replace(Str, StringToDelete, "")
        ' MsgBox finalString
        Cells(i, 1) = finalString
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Seems to be good, thy, The only problem, that i have around 500 rows with this beginning and with this ending...And with another contains...I need to search all rows that begins and ends with this words and delete it...I have 500 records in a column (its links that i dont need, i only need the comment at the end), so i need to separate them...I tryed with search and replace but all the 500 is other...Only the beginning and the end the same...
Its possible to make somehow ?

Comment: I mean similar like this (this works -only select- in MS Word, but not in Excel):

Sub Macro ()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "http:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Extend
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ".jpg"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub

Comment: this can easily be done with help of `FOR` loop and `Cells` function. I've updated my answer